# Time complexity of Max counters

Tags: java, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, complexity

As per the instructions are given in [MaxCounters-Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/max_counters/),

> You are given `N` counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:
>
> - `increase(X)` − counter `X` is increased by 1,
> - `max counter` − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
>
> A non-empty array `A` of `M` integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:
>
> if `A[K] = X`, such that 1 ≤ `X` ≤ `N`, then operation `K` is `increase(X)`,
>   if `A[K] = N + 1` then operation `K` is `max counter`.

I have written this code

```
public int[] maxCount(int[]A,int N) {
    int[] I = new int[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        try {
            I[A[i] - 1]++;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Arrays.sort(I);
            Arrays.fill(I, I[I.length - 1]);
        }
    }
    return I;
}
```

It gives correct answers for all test cases. Any Idea to do this with time complexity O(N). Its currently on O(N*M).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets start with the time complexity of your current algorithm:

`for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)` has a time complexity of `O(M)` (Length of array 'A' is 'M')
`Arrays.sort(I)` has a time complexity of `O(N*log(N))`<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219777/the-running-time-for-arrays-sort-method-in-java)</sup>
`Arrays.fill(I, I[I.length - 1])` has a time complexity of `O(N)` (The number of counters)

That means the complexity of your current algorithm is `O(N^2 * log(N) * M)`.

You can replace the sorting by keeping track of the maximum value for all counters like this:

```
public int[] maxCount(int[] A, int N)
{
    int[] I = new int[N];
    //Initialize the max value to 0
    int max = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] == N + 1)
        {
            Arrays.fill(I, max);
        }
        else
        {
            I[A[i] - 1]++;

            if (I[A[i] - 1] > max)
            {
                //Update the max value 
                max = I[A[i] - 1];
            }
        }
    }
    return I;
}
```

The time complexity of this version is now `O(M * N)`. This version is also using `if` statements to control the flow of the program as opposed to exceptions which is an anti-pattern<sup>[2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)</sup>.

**UPDATE**: I've used the suggestion of **Mees de Vries** from his comment to implement a data structure for the problem. The complexity of the function reading the instruction `incrementCounters()` is `O(n)`.

```
public class SynchronizedCounters
{
    private int[] counters;
    private int size;
    private int base = 0;
    private int max = 0;
    private final int INSTRUCTION_OFFSET = 1;

    public SynchronizedCounters(int size)
    {
        this.size = size;
        this.counters = new int[size];
    }

    public void incrementCounters(int[] instructions)
    {
        for (int instruction : instructions)
        {
            int instruct = instruction - INSTRUCTION_OFFSET;

            if (instruct >= size)
            {
                base = max;
            }
            else
            {
                normalizeCounter(instruct);

                counters[instruct]++;

                if (counters[instruct] > max)
                {
                    max = counters[instruct];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Integer getCounterValue(int counter)
    {
        normalizeCounter(counter);
        return counters[counter];
    }

    private void normalizeCounter(int index)
    {
        counters[index] = java.lang.Math.max(counters[index],base);
    }
}
```

Example using the class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SynchronizedCounters synchronizedCounters = new SynchronizedCounters(5);
        synchronizedCounters.incrementCounters(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 6, 2, 3});
        System.out.println("Value of first counter: " + synchronizedCounters.getCounterValue(0));
    }
```

Output:

```
Value of first counter: 5
```

<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219777/the-running-time-for-arrays-sort-method-in-java)</sup> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219777/the-running-time-for-arrays-sort-method-in-java

<sup>[2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl)</sup> https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Comment: You can improve the running time to `O(n)` by keeping track of two maximums: the current maximum of all array cells, and the most recent maximum to which all cells were updated. Then, before increasing the value in a cell, make sure its value is at least the update-maximum that you're keeping track of, otherwise set it to that update-maximum. (Reading the array is left implicit here, but this check-and-update should also be done each time you want to read a cell.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries Thank you for the suggestion, I've updated my answer with an implementation of it.

Comment: You can shorten normalizeCounters with `counters[index] = java.lang.Math.max(counters[index],base)`. Additionally, I don't think you need the out of bounds check in getCounterValue. If it's asking for an out of bounds counter, it SHOULD throw the appropriate exception.